# button Cancel not show in messagebox

Tags: vb.net

i have some problem. when i run this project, only messagebox button ok appear, but button cancel do not show.
 i'm using visual basic express edition 2008. and this is my codding.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If MessageBox.Show("Sila Pastikan Data MyKad Anda." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nama:" & TextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "No I/C: " & icTextBox.Text &, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then
            ' nothing
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("ok")
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use Show() with a MessageBoxButtons setting, but that call takes 3 parameters. Try adding a title to the call;

```
If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to edit Student data with Id." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Name:" & TextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "No ID: " & idTextBox.Text, "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then
    ' nothing
Else
    MessageBox.Show("ok")
End If
```